# Keras autoencoder negative loss and val_loss with data in range [-1 1]

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I am trying to adapt keras autoencoder example to a my data. I have the following network:

```python
Xtrain = np.reshape(Xtrain, (len(Xtrain), 28, 28, 2))
Xtest = np.reshape(Xtest, (len(Xtest), 28, 28, 2))

input_signal = Input(shape=(28, 28, 2))
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_signal)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same', name='encoder')(x)

# added Dense layers, is that correct?
encoded2 = Flatten()(encoded)
encoded2 = Dense(128, activation='sigmoid')(encoded2)
encoded2 = Dense(128, activation='softmax')(encoded2)
encoded3 = Reshape((4, 4, 8))(encoded2)

x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded3)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(inputs=input_signal, outputs=decoded)
encoder = Model(input_signal, encoded2)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder.fit(Xtrain, Xtrain, epochs=100, batch_size=128, shuffle=True, validation_data=(Xtest, Xtest))
```

And, when I'm running on MNIST data, which are normalized to [0,1] everything works fine, but with my data that are in range [-1,1] I only see negative losses and 0.0000 accuracy while training. If I do data = np.abs(data), training starts and looks that goes well, but doing abs() on data makes no reasons to train data fakes.

The data I'm trying to feed to network are IQ channels of signal, 1st channel for real part, and 2nd channel for imag part, so both are normalized to a [-1 1], and both often contains very low values, e.g. 5e-12. I have shaped them to a (28,28,2) input.

I have also added Dense layers in the middle of autoencoder, as I wish to make predictions about classes (that are fitted automatically) when autoencoder completes training. Am I did this correctly, does this breaks the network?

Comment: I think you should try with tanh as activation for your final layer. sigmoid puts its outputs between (0,1) so if you want to decode what you encoded your output should be between 
[-1,1] and that is exactly what tanh does.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your question, including your understanding of autoencoders and their usage. I strongly suggest at least going through the Keras blog post [Building Autoencoders in Keras](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) (if you do have gone through it, arguably you have to do it again, this time more thoroughly).

A few general points, most of which are included in the above linked post:

1. Autoencoders are **not** used for classification, hence it makes no sense to ask for a metric such as accuracy. Similarly, since the fitting objective is the reconstruction of their input, categorical cross entropy is not the correct loss function to use (try binary cross entropy instead).
2. The very existence of the intermediate dense layers you use is puzzling, and even more puzzling is the choice of a `sigmoid` layer followed by a `softmax` one; the same holds for the `sigmoid` choice in your final, `decoded` layer. Both these activation functions are normally used for classification purposes at final layers, so again refer to point (1) above.
3. I strongly suggest you start with a model demonstrated in the blog post linked above, and, if necessary, *incrementally* modify it to fit your purpose, as I am not sure what you have built here can even qualify as an autoencoder in the first place.

Comment: First, I want to reply to 3: This code completely is a code of model from this Keras blog post, what I am doing right now again. The only thing changed incrementally was changing of the loss function (and adding dense layers which I have already removed). And again, this works on mnist dataset, but won't work on my one, which contains negative values.

Comment: Indeed to 1 and 2: yes, I need some kind of unsupervised classifier, and thought that autoencoder would fit my needs. I am doing supervised classification on my data using convolutional network, but have really no idea on how to make it unsupervised.

Comment: @RandyVogel "works on MNIST" doesn't say much, if your data are not somewhat similar to MNIST (there are even a lot of things that work well on MNIST, but not on other computer vision problems). In any case, without more details on your data, I doubt that anyone can offer more help (even your suspicion that the different range is the issue might prove irrelevant).

Comment: these are [[[ 1.79...e-16 -5.97...e-17], [ 7.98123213e-04  1.433128e-09 ] ... etc, shaped to 28x28x2. I took this shape from my other conv net, which is "conv2d->pool->conv2d->pool->flatten->dense->dense softmax" and that gets an accuracy about 85% on this dataset. I wonder why autoencoder wont eat negatives, if i do abs(data) it eats my data, and shows stats like on mnist dataset, but surely never converges well.

Comment: I disagree (not downvote) with the point 1, the context vector can be used for anything and is not restricted to reconstruction. Secondly, if you have reconstruction for text representation, your outputs can be categorical (hot-encoded for same input's integar index) and there you can be using categorical-cross entropy for reconstruction as well, wont we?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing between binary ('sigmoid') and categorical ('softmax' and  'categorical_crossentropy'). Change the following:

1. Remove the dense layers in between and feed 'encoded' instead of 'encoded3' to the decoder
2. Change the autoencoder loss to 'binary_crossentropy'

Alternatively if you really want to try the dense layers in between, just use them without an activation function (None)

Comment: Tried, removed dense layers, changed to adam/binary_crossentropy. Now I am getting training loss falling from 0.6 to 0.1 during first epoch, with val_loss -0.01 and 0.000e+00 to both accuracies, then loss freezes at -0.0127 and val_loss at -0.032 for all the following epochs.

I am not sure I wish to use dense layers in between, I need somehow to get encoded representation class and I want to have it integer, so I need some kind of output with: autodetected_class1, autodetected_class73

Comment: This is how it's written in this Keras original example, and it works for MNIST data in range [0 .. 1], but won't work with my data in range [-1 .. 1].